# Reactjs - Current User from JWT token

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, jwt

So, I have created a **django-rest-framework** *backend* with **JWT Authentication** and now, I am trying to solve the problem where when user manually provides a **URL**, **I have to check If the user was previously logged in**.

So since, I am storing the **token** to `localStorage` when the user logged in. I am doing this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('token')) {
        // fetch current user
        this.props.ctx.toggleLoggedIn()
        // this.props.ctx.setUsername('')
    }   
}
```

If I find a `token` in `localStorage`, then I have to **fetch** the *current User* and then, **toggleLoggedIn** and also **set the current user's username in the `context`**.

So, I am planning to create another **API** *end-point* which provides the current user when a `token` is given. The problem is I don't know how to start that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be that i misunderstand, but for me it seems like you're trying to solve this a bit backwards. When the user login, get token and store this in localStorage. Right after login fetch the user profile and store this as well.

If the user manually provides a url, you should now have both token and user. If you don't have a token or it's expired, redirect to login page and clear local storage.

I would create a higher order component that checks if the token is valid and use this for all "protected" pages.